# Weird problem with appendParagraph method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created a form, used by some users at my school, that uploads a document and creates a new formatted document with all the uploads, which can be images or other docs. At this moment I am having problems with one .docx file that contains some lists, paragraphs and 2 images inside paragraphs. The part of the code I am using is:

...

```
// Insert Google doc 
function insertGdoc(vdoc,IDgdoc,asignat)
{
  var Gdoc=DocumentApp.openById(IDgdoc).getBody();
  var vdoc_id=vdoc.getId();
  var docBody=vdoc.getBody();
  docBody.appendPageBreak();
  docBody.appendParagraph("Documento de "+asignat).setBold(false);
  docBody.appendHorizontalRule();

  var insertaBody = DocumentApp.openById(IDgdoc).getActiveSection();
  var numElements = insertaBody.getNumChildren();

  for( var jj = 0; jj < numElements; ++jj ) 
  {
    var element = insertaBody.getChild(jj).copy();
    var type = element.getType();

    try {
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
      {
        docBody.appendParagraph(element.asParagraph());
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        docBody.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE)
        docBody.appendHorizontalRule();
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK)
        docBody.appendPageBreak();
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
      {
        docBody.appendListItem(element);
        var glyphType = element.getGlyphType(); 
        element.setGlyphType(glyphType);
      }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }    
}

// Insert MS Word doc
function insertDoc(vdoc,IDdoc,asignat)
{
  var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(IDdoc);
  var blob=docx.getBlob();
  var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
  var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
  insertGdoc(vdoc,file.id,asignat);
}
```

...

After many attempts, I discovered that the elements that are causing the problems are both pictures. By using the try..catch I can avoid the error by not handling the pictures, but the final document is incomplete. I have also tried to use Utilities.sleep to give the server more time to perform actions and even to close and reopen the document, with no change or worse results. 
Another option I discovered here in stackoverflow was to try appending child elements from the paragraph, differentiating if they are pictures, which could copy the first of my pictures (although with size and position changed from the original) but not the second one.
Which is most annoying is that this failure happens if I use the form to do all the process, but if I try the operation manually from the console it works and the whole source document with both pictures is copied to the final doc.
Thank you very much in advance if you can give me any advice.
Rafael

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Document for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Certainly. The document is a .docx file and has no personal information.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pim2uKPmIPBifNhLOMtSOFbxXN2eDr4d"     I did another test: If I upload and handle the file in the form, it fails, but if I upload the file to Drive, add a menu option in the form and go to the function via this menu, it handles the file Ok. Is it then that the file handling through forms is different?

Comment: Thank you for providing sample Document and additional information. About `If I upload and handle the file in the form, it fails`, I cannot understand about your situation. Can you explain about the detail information?

Comment: Ye, I will try to explain it with more detail. One of the process in my school is to compound a tasks document for some pupils from time to time. These tasks are provided by a group of teachers. The way to do it is sending from the school office a request to send a task, via email, to that group of teachers, When the tasks are received they are joined in a document, which is later handed to the pupil. All this process is done using forms in order to make it easier and automatic.

Comment: Esentially this sytem has been working without problems but I found an error when one teacher attached the .docx document I mention to the task. So, if he uses the form to upload the task with the document attached, it fails (it does not handle the inline pictures). but If he uploads the document manually, opens the form in edit mode and uses a menu option that performs the same procedure, then it works well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, can you provide the sample docx file for replicating your issue?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I wrote a link to the file in a previous comment.This is it again: drive.google.com/open?id=1Pim2uKPmIPBifNhLOMtSOFbxXN2eDr4d. In order to repeat the issue maybe you should have the form and the whole script attached. Let me know if this is the case. Rafael.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm the docx file. When your sample docx file is used, when the function `insertDoc()` is directly run by the script editor, the script works. But when the function `insertDoc()` is run by the OnSubmit event trigger, the script doesn't work. If my understanding is correct, when the script doesn't work, can you provide the error message or other information?

Comment: Yes, when the script does not work, the error message is not very useful IMHO. In spanish it says 'Acción no permitida' which can be translated as 'Action not allowed'. Maybe the corresponding error in english is 'Service unavailable', but I am not sure. Rafael.

Comment: By the way, the operation that issues the error is 'appendParagraph' with paragraphs that contain pictures. I found a code that handles child elements in the paragraph and that code works with one of the problematic paragraphs (although the picture loses asociated properties like size and alignment) but not the other one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that your issue cannot be resolved soon. From your replying, for example, when the image is removed from the Document, will the error be disappeared?

Comment: I have been really busy since my last message, and I could not test what you suggested, Tanaike. I have just done it now and it works, so the problem seems to be in the pictures. I do not expect to get the solution, but here is what I think: why handling operations with GAS does not have the same result as manually, i.e., if I open a Google doc and add a .docx the the result is perfect. But if I use the code I have for the script, the result is not the same. Is there any method for handling google docs?

Comment: Thank you for replying. The Document service and Docs API are growing now. So it might not be able to replicate all manual actions using the script. If the reason of your current issue is due to this, I think that in the current stage, it might be difficult to directly resolve it soon. At that time, I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for your support Tanaike. I will try to circumvent the issue changing my procedure. Rafael

Comment: Hi, Rafael. You have provided a lot of valuable/useful information in response to @Tanaike comments. Would you now please edit your question to ensure that all of that information is included in the body of the question (where other users can/will read it). If there is any extra information that will enable a user to understand your scenario or visualise how a successful outcome would appear, then please also include that extra information.